# Rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

I'm finding different results for the 3D rotation matrix in the XY plane from different sources and I was hoping for someone to help clarify. In my "applications of vector calculus" book, the matrix for a rotation by $a$ counterclockwise is given by $$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} \cos(a) & \sin(a) & 0 \\ -\sin(a) & \cos(a) & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 1 \end{array} \right),$$

whereas on wikipedia, my other algebra and geometry notes and other sources I'm finding the result for the counterclockwise rotation by $a$ to be $$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} \cos(a) & -\sin(a) & 0 \\ \sin(a) & \cos(a) & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 1 \end{array} \right).$$

I would have assumed that there was just an error in my vector calc notes but both are using a diagram like the one linked to justify the matrix but when I look at the diagram it looks like it should be the first matrix to me. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Counterclockwise_rotation.png

Which one should it be?

Comment: It's the second one.  Just multiply that matrix by a vector in the $x$-$y$ plane (i.e. its third component will be $0$) to confirm.  The first matrix performs a *clockwise* rotation.

Comment: To go from one to the other switch $a$ with $-a$.

Comment: Thanks, but in regards to the image link I posted, wouldn't the x-axis be moved to xcos(a) + ysin(a) as, as the diagram shows, it's moved towards positive y when rotated counterclockwise?

Comment: Which book are you using for vector calculus?

Comment: One made specifically for my university (southampton). Thanks for all the help all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick way to check.

Note that the columns of any $3\times 3$ matrix are the images of $(1\ 0\ 0)^T, (0\ 1\ 0)^T$, and $(0\ 0\ 1)^T$.

Thus, we can see that when (for example) $\theta = \pi/2$, the image of $(1, 0, 0)^T$ under the first matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\pi/2)\\ -\sin(\pi/2)\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\ -1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

So, which rotation - clockwise or counterclockwise - by a quarter-turn sends the point $(1, 0, 0)$ to $(0, -1, 0)$?

Comment: I want to say clockwise but this seems to fly in the the face of everything I'm finding online

Comment: You're correct, the first matrix you listed (the one in your book) is a clockwise rotation through an angle $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Counterclockwise rotation by an angle $\alpha$ of $(x,y)$ corresponds to the multiplication
$$
(x+iy)(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)=
(x\cos\alpha-y\sin\alpha)+i(x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha)
$$
so the correct matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha & 0 \\
\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha  & 0 \\
0          & 0           & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
because
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha \\
\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x\cos\alpha-y\sin\alpha \\ x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Since 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\alpha  & \sin\alpha & 0 \\
-\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0 \\
0          & 0           & 1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha & 0 \\
\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha  & 0 \\
0          & 0           & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$
the first matrix you list is rotation by $-\alpha$ counterclockwise, that is, by $\alpha$ clockwise.